# Outlook Macro/VBA to compare FROM and REPLY TO address and alert if different?

Tags: vba, outlook

Is this doable in an Outlook 2013 macro/VBA? I'm not sure where to start. Ideally it would trigger for every incoming email, and pop up an alert if the FROM and REPLY TO addresses are different.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863686(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Application class.

This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, MailItem, MeetingItem, or SharingItem. The EntryIDsCollection string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item.

The NewMailEx event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the EntryIDCollection array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869893.aspx) method and process the item.

Also you may create a rule which may call a VBA sub. The sub should look like the following one:

```
 Public Sub Test(mail as MailItem)
  ' test
 End Sub
```

Finally, you may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) article helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In the ThisOutlookSession add the following code - you'll need to update the Inbox location, or whichever folder you're watching.
I don't think I'm looking at the right property with `Item.Recipients` - you'll need to find ReplyTo.
Also the recipient address may not always show the correct email address - search the internet for a function called `ResolveDisplayNameToSMTP`

Also - I haven't tested it. :)

The procedure will become active when you run the Application_StartUp routine, or by closing and reopening Outlook.

```
Dim WithEvents MyInboxFolder As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()

    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace

    Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set MyInboxFolder = ns.Folders.item("Mailbox - Darren Bartrup-Cook").Folders.item("Inbox").Items

End Sub

Sub MyInboxFolder_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

    Dim sSenderEmailAddress As String
    Dim vReplyRecipient As Variant

    sSenderEmailAddress = item.SenderEmailAddress

    For Each vReplyRecipient In item.Recipients
        If vReplyRecipient.Address = sSenderEmailAddress Then
            MsgBox "The same"
        End If
    Next vReplyRecipient

End Sub

Private Sub Application_Quit()

    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set MyInboxFolder = Nothing
    Set ns = Nothing

End Sub
```

Edit after looking up NewMailEx that Eugene Astafiev mentions - **This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook** - definitely worth looking further into as it will capture all folders, not just the Inbox.

Comment: Did you mean to use the ReplyRecipients collection instead of Recipients?

Comment: Yes, I probably did. :)